# How to write complex validating functions regarding searching in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a model: `Lecture(start_time, end_time, location)`. I want to write a validation function in `lecture.rb` so that I can check whether the location conflicts when I create a new lecture. The logic is: find existing lectures that have the same location with the new lecture, then check if their time overlap, if it does, add error messages.

I do not know how to write correct ruby class to achieve this.

Comment: Since there are also many models need the same kind of validation functions, the answers will be very useful for me. Thank you!

Comment: The uniqueness in rails is not capable to do this, because this scope can only check certain data, but a range. If there is a way to add a function in scope?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking to create a custom validation in your model. These are described in details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :duplicate_location

  private

    def duplicate_location
      <validation code>
    end
end
```

This validation will be run every time you attempt to change anything in your instance. Check this for [a list of callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) Active Record performs when creating/modifying an instance of a Model.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how to write it. I have tried： Lecture.all.each do |user|
        if (user.start_time - end_time) * (start_time - user.end_time) >= 0
          errors.add(:Base, "time overlaps")    but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [before save](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) callback. Call a custom validator method in `before_save` inside your lecture model.

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :check_unique_schedule

    private

    def check_unique_schedule
        //it should fetch all existing lectures
        lectures_at_venue = self.class.where(location: self.location)
        //now check schedule of existing lectures at same venue
        lectures_at_venue.each do |l|
          //check time overlap here with self 
          //.....
          if overlap
             errors.add(location: "location is not available on dates")
          end
       end
    end
end
```

Probably some database level uniqueness constraint might also be possible, but I am not sure about them. But do read about uniqueness constraint and scope as well.

Comment: Best practice says that before_save callbacks should be used for altering the instance before saving it, so that SQL won't run multiple transactions. Anything related to validations should be done within the validation callbacks.

Comment: Also, your answer runs a very unefficient example on how this check could be performed. Adding time related (start_date & end_date) constriants to the query could graleatly improve it. But those depend on how "overlapping" is defined in this particular case.